# Add a percent symbol to label in specific ggplots and not in other plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a shiny app, with multiple ggplot, few show percent labels others rounded numbers. All are getting returned by same function that creates the ggplot. `percent_flag` is passed as a parameter to function for same. I tried below logic but it doesnt works. I don't have option of creating additional column to satisfy the creiteria.

```
geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(percent_flag == 1,
                             paste(round(BIAS_contribution, 2), "%", sep = ""),
                             comma(BIAS_contribution)),
              y = (start + end) / 2)
```

Comment: Your code works fine, e.g. using the `iris` dataset. So the issue is probably related to your data or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a basic if-clause:

```
library(ggplot2)
percent_flag <- 1

# base plot
p <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))

# with percent flag
if(percent_flag == 1){
  p2 <- p +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Petal.Width, "%")))
  
  # withput percent flag
} else {
  p2 <- p +
    geom_text(aes(label = Petal.Width))
}
p2
```